# How can I filter outlying matches based on proximity to other matches?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection

How can I filter outlying matches based on proximity to other matches?

I'm trying to find a small, similar image, inside a large image. Template matching doesn't seems to handle the minute differences very well so I am trying the feature match approach. After much tinkering around I can get it to do a fairly decent job at matching but the outliers will cause problems. I have homography in my code which doesn't seem necessary, but It has a positive impact on getting the correct matches. Is there some other alternative that would be more effective?

Ultimately, I would like to find the matches, (See image 1) filter out the key points that don't align with the smaller image, (See image 2) determine the boundaries of the smaller image within the large, then find the coordinates for the center of that boundary.

[https://ibb.co/c0xC6m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZuc3.png)

[https://ibb.co/mjSZK6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTVF.png)

**Additional images:**

Image to search: (They aren't formatted as images because of an error saying I had code that wasn't formatted.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyVAv.png

Unedited world map:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u3FN.png

Original search result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrX63.png

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import remove_map_dots as rm

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 0

img1 = rm.removemapdots()
img2 = cv2.imread('worldmapsnippet1.png')

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(hessianThreshold=10, upright=True, extended=True)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SURF/SIFT
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

good = []
for m, n in matches:
    good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 10) #RANSAC LMEDS RHO
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h, w, _ = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    print(h)
    print(w)
else:
    print("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0, 255, 0), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3), plt.show()
```

Comment: `findHomography()` with the `RANSAC` option will filter out outliers for you. That's what `RANSAC` is for. You're still drawing all the keypoints even though some have been filtered out when finding the homography. The `matchesMask` will tell you which of the `good` matches were used or not. Also both your images are the same.

Comment: Ah see that's where I'm getting confused. RANSAC appears to work as I would expect with the majority of the matches, however, why would it still allow those pesky outliers to remain? Since both of my images are a top down map, is it possible perspectiveTransform is having a negative impact on my results since there really won't be a perspective shift for this application? Thanks for the heads-up about the images, I fixed it.

Comment: `findHomography()` will indeed probably add a *little* perspective shift, but very very little. I wouldn't worry about it too much in general, *but* since this case is very simple, you could try to filter the outliers yourself and use [`cv2.estimateRigidTransform`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform) instead to only find translation & rotation (or an affine warp with `fullAffine=True`. However note that RANSAC is not an option for this case, it simply uses least squares to estimate the transform.

Comment: RANSAC is not a perfect filter. It takes a random sample of four matches, computes the homography using least squares with those four points, and then scores the points depending on how well that homography worked. It then repeats this process until the probability that the points are all inliers is very high. However it doesn't go through every possible homography (that'd be way too computationally expensive), so it doesn't always filter perfectly. Can you post the two original images with no markup?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds How would I need to adjust my input for  cv2.estimateRigidTransform?
This returns None:  
`src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)`
`dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)`

    `M = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(src_pts, dst_pts, True)`
   `print(M)`

Comment: Update: I can get `cv2.estimateRigidTransform` to actually plot points if I feed it an array like `np.array([[56, 45], [46, 34], [67, 55]], np.float32)` and change `dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)` to include `.reshape(-1, 2)` but when I convert my actual src/dst points to this format it still returns None. So, I suppose this is where filtering is needed. Not sure how to proceed here, I promise I read the documentation but it’s not the easiest for me to grasp.

Comment: Oh! I just looked through the source code and I see that `estimateRigidTransform()` also uses RANSAC. Didn't know that. The result gets set to `None` only if the RANSAC algorithm doesn't converge within the allotted number of iterations. To your original question: the main thing you're interested in is the center of the template, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal. The goal is to match that small part of the map on to the larger, then get the center coodinate of that match on the large image. The purpose of this is so my program can identify where my player’s location is on a minimap with respect to the world map. I plan on using this info to help navigate my player around the world by clicking certain points on the minimap to reach a destination on the world map. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's what I figured, cool project! Template matching makes way more sense for this IMO, what 'minute differences' are you concerned about? It's okay if there's differences, you don't need an exact match---the minimum location should be good enough to use. Feature matching is not what you want to use for this---it only looks at tiny image patches around feature locations, so it doesn't do very well on repetitive patterns.

Comment: You can also speed up template matching quite a bit; once you have found your location on the full map, then you know that the next time you search it should be in an area near the last found location. See [this project](https://youtu.be/m99H6oH46E8) I gave a talk about last year; Mario's head is the template, but the white box around Mario's head is the search area. You can reduce to only look in the ROI around your last template location so that you don't get positive matches elsewhere. You can view the code from the demo [here](https://github.com/alkasm/track-mario-desertpy).

Comment: Here's the roadblock I've hit with template matching: [cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED](https://ibb.co/dGKYXR).
I'm following [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#py-template-matching). I know the image is slightly different but, it should still detect, right? That's why I attempted to feature match instead; at least the majority of keypoints are in the right area.

Comment: It looks like the template is a different size than the region it's looking for in the map maybe, but I can't tell for sure. The sizes need to be the same, so the template needs to be scaled so that it corresponds to the same size section on the map. It might be better to include the color information as well (you can just do template matching on the three channels separately, add the resultz into a single channel array, and *then* use `minMaxLoc()`. Feel free to email me (see my SO profile) and I might be able to help in a better forum for chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue with your template matching approach is indeed the size of the template and image. The template is larger than the corresponding region of the template, giving false readings. The simple solution is to resize your template so that the region corresponds exactly to the right size region in the map.

Feature matching *can* be used for this as well, but template matching makes far more sense here. The only difference between the two images will be translation, which template matching can handle really well.

With template matching, it's also easy to make nice optimizations, like reducing the search area to be around the last found location in the map. You can also create a threshold by looking at the last few found locations---so that you know when you're not finding the correct location and need to re-look at the whole map. For e.g., if you teleport it won't be around the last location, so you'll need to go over the whole image. But you know that the `min` of your SSD image from the last (say) 5 frames were [100, 150, 130, 180, 100] so if your next frame was way different (say the `min` in your region was 500) then you go and check the whole map again and find the min, and again start tracking that region.